# JQuery Dynamically Generate Div By Drag Drop List Item

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to dynamically generate a Div with a heading (works with onClick method) but I would like to make this work with drag n drop. When I drop the list item it should generate the Div with a header with preferred header size.) I've got all this to work with onClick event.

So my Actual question is how to make it work with drag & drop.
What it does now is moving my list item to my form where the generated Div should appear.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li').draggable({ containment: 'document', revert: true});

    $('#form').droppable({ hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.drags',
    drop: function GenerateHeading () { /* Something wrong here */
    var heading = prompt("Pick a heading size between h1 and h6");
    if (heading != "h1" && heading != "h2" && heading != "h3" && heading != "h4" && heading != "h5" && heading != "h6") {
        alert("Please insert a valid heading size!");
    } else {
    if(counter>3){
            alert("Only 3 Headings allowed");
            return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
         .attr("id", 'HeadingDiv' + counter).attr("class", 'HeadingDiv');

    newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<' + heading + '>Heading #'+ counter + ' : </' + heading + '>');

    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#form");


    counter++;
     }
     }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a hard time understanding whats going on here but I cleaned it up to the best of my ability:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('li').draggable({ containment: 'document', revert: true});

    $('#form').droppable(
    {
        hoverClass: 'border',
        accept: '.drags',
        drop: function()
        {
            var aHeaderOptions = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6"];
            var heading = prompt("Pick a heading size between h1 and h6");

            if (aHeaderOptions.indexOf(heading) != -1)
            {
                alert("Please insert a valid heading size!");
            }
            else
            {
                if($('#form .heading').length > 3)
                {
                    alert("Only 3 Headings allowed");
                    return false;
                }

                var newTextBoxDiv = $("<div />").attr(
                {
                    "id": 'HeadingDiv'+counter,
                    "class": 'HeadingDiv'
                });

                var heading = jQuery('<'+heading+'>')
                    .attr({ "class": "heading" })
                    .text('Heading #'+ counter + ':');

                jQuery("#form").prepend(heading);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

If you could provide HTML components I would be happy to look further at what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make a form builder and I'm trying to generate a div with a heading. It works onclick but I want to make it work on drop. I should show it live. I'll upload it temporaly: http://low-budgetwebservice.be/project/webbuilder.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm a total newb :p Since I had already created the function I just had to call it on drop!
Thanks a lot for even trying to clear my chaos :p !
like this:

```
 $(function () {
                $('li').draggable({ containment: 'document', revert: true});

                $('#form').droppable({ hoverClass: 'border', accept: '.drags',
                drop: GenerateHeading()
                });
            });</script>
```